# how to acess formcontrols inside formarray in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following form:

```
 form = this.builder.group({
  form2: this.builder.array([
      this.builder.group({
    name: new FormControl(),
    surname: new FormControl(),

  })
]),
  });
```

in my oninit I am doing this to set one formcontrol with a setvalue

```
 this.form.controls.personNameField.setValue(this.person.name);
```

But this does not work, probably due to the controls being inside an formarray. But how can I access my formarray controls?

Comment: You could try making a nested call to access your control, ie. `form.controls['form.someControlName']`. And on a different note, you'll want to look into `setValue vs patchValue`. Using the former requires you to provide all `FormControls` entries in that `FormGroup` while the latter enables you to patch single values.

Comment: Thanks how do I have to change it in my html? I tried something like this: <form [formGroup]="form[form2]">. But it says TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'form2.name'

Answer (score 1):

You can add controls with values in a `FormArray` like this:

```
get form2Array(){
  return this.form.controls.form2 as FormArrray;
}

// If form control exists at index
addPerson(index: number, person: any){
  const personFormGroup = this.form2Array.at(index) as FormGroup
  personFormGroup.setValue(person) //handle according to your code
}

// If form control does not exist at index
addPerson(index: number, person: any){
  this.form2Array.at(index).setControl(index, this.builder.group({
    name: this.builder.control({}),
    surname: this.builder.control({}),
  }))
  const personFormGroup = this.form2Array.at(index) as FormGroup
  personFormGroup.setValue(person) //handle according to your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reach your form control with the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
  (this.form.get('form2') as FormArray).at(0).patchValue({ name: 'test' });
}
```

So we get the formarray inside the parent group, then get the first formgroup in the formarray (at index 0) and patch the value for the `name` formcontrol.